# How to train a model for recognizing two objects?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

Ive got two separate models, one for mask recognition and another for face recognition. The problem now is that how do I combine these both models so that it performs in unison as  a single model which is able to :-

1. Recognize whether or not a person is wearing mask
2. Simultaneously recognize who that person is if he isn't wearing mask apart from warning about no mask.

What are the possibilities I have to solve this problem!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to combine the both models and train them you have to train them seprately. And after training the model first you have to check with the mask detection model what's the probability/confidence score that there's a mask detected and if the probability is low say like 40%-45% then you have to use the other model that recognises the person.

Answer (score 0):

#### Possibility 1 : Independent models

Adding on to the solution by [IAmParadox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13765172/iamparadox), you could train the models separately. An important point to note is that while training face recognition model, the input set should contain only images without the mask. This because we are providing it only images without mask during test time. During test time, for mask recognition model, you could threshold (to get 0/1) it to decide whether input must be passed to face recognition model as well.

#### Possibility 2 : Use of shared layers

(I would prefer this pipeline over the first due to better efficiency and optimization. It could also help in the model train faster.)
You could have the initial few conv layers common to both models, and then have 2 branches, (one for mask recognition and one for face recognition respectively), from this intermediate representation. Thus you would have one model for both tasks with input being the image and output being concatenated outputs of both the branches. This would save significant computation reduction. Both the tasks would have similar features in the lower layers.